# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. [Flutter]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
class MessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MessageScreenState createState() => _MessageScreenState();
}

class _MessageScreenState extends State<MessageScreen> {
  var fanMessage = '';
  var userDocument;
  var userId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getId();
  }

  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();
  void _messageSubmit() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('messages/ne6MUaXi2wup9WOcZq85/alerts')
        .add({'text': messageController.text});
  }

  Future _getId() async {
    var test = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      userId = test.uid;
      print(userId);
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(userId)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        userDocument = documentSnapshot.data['role'];
      });
    });
  }

  // Widget _getId() {
  //   return FutureBuilder(future: Firestore.instance.collection('users'),child: Text());
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('User ID: ${userId}');

    print('User Role: ${userDocument}');
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),
          child: AppBar(
            title: Text('Fan Page'),
            actions: [
              DropdownButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.more_vert,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.color,
                ),
                items: [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            Text('Logout')
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      value: 'logout')
                ],
                onChanged: (itemIdentifier) {
                  if (itemIdentifier == 'logout') {
                    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                  }
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('messages/ne6MUaXi2wup9WOcZq85/alerts')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
            if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            final documents = streamSnapshot.data.documents;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 10,

                  // decoration:
                  // BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 20.0, 5.0, 20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        documents[index]['text'],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Visibility(
          visible: checkIfAdmin(),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 70),
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                          _buildPopupDialog(context),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  bool checkIfAdmin() {
    // getData();
    // print(userDocument['role']);
    if (userDocument == 'admin') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Okay so what I want to do is, show that floatingActionButton for 'admin' user role only. The logic seems to be working as this happens when I hot reload once after launching th app. When I launch the app and login then I get a red window with an error saying "Invalid argument(s)" and when I hot reload without changing anything, I get my screen and then it works fine. Why is this happening? I have not totally understood state concept yet. So please help!

EDIT: I have stopped getting red screen error messages. Instead the app starts. But from what I have checked.

My problem is that my app works fine only after hot reload. Only after hot reload admin sees the floatingActionButton.

In debug console before hot reload, I get this error:

**Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.**

Answer (score 1):

in your case ,just wrap the fab with a visibility widget and set its visible property to true/false.
so u got:

```
floatingActionButton: Visibility(
 visible: checkIfAdmin(),
 child: FloatingActionButton(
 child: Icon(Icons.add),
 onPressed: () {},
 ),
 ),
```

and a method:

```
bool checkIfAdmin(){
if(admin){
return true;}
else{
return false;
}   
}
```

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for replying. Problem is not in displaying is for admin or user. The functionality for displaying it to the admin or the user is working. But it is working correctly only after hot reload.

Comment: I tried this approach to get admin or not, but the error remains same. When app is installed and I log in, then I get invalid arguments as error on a red screen

Answer (score 0):

Reviewed your code a bit, it seems your setState method is not causing a rebuild, because you call setState for userid which has no role in the state of your application.
Also consider moving

```
Firestore.instance
.collection('users')
.document(userId)
.get()
.then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
userDocument = documentSnapshot.data['role'];
// print(userDocument);
});
```

out of build method.

Comment: What I have encountered is I am not getting value from async function _getId() on time. I get that when I hot reload the app. I don't know why I am not getting the value

Comment: dude ure app is breaking caz ure calling Firestore.instance
.collection('users')
.document(userId)
.get() on null,becaz the server hasnt returned the value for userid(so its null) yet that u call this.

Comment: set the value of userDocument, right after u get the user id.

Comment: Hey. I did what you said. I have updated the code. Please check?

Comment: hi ,did u get rid of null error?

Comment: No. I am still having the null error when I initialize the app.

Comment: check run,see whats causing null error.

Comment: another thing you can do is to create another screen(as first screen) and use flutter flutter_spinkit package to show a loader while the data being retrieved.so in first screens initstate ,you call _getId()

Comment: this way u can make sure ure receiving data from server before heading over to  ure main screen.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit